# Group by part of string in SOQL

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, group-by

Is there any way to Group By part of string in SOQL.

For example something like:

Select Id, Name from Object__c group by Name.substringBetween('.','.')

So query by part of a string field and not the whole field.

The other approach that can be taken to this is to create a formula field that takes the substring between the name field, and then use that field in the group by, if there is no other option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that my answer serves your purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to use specific field values in `GROUP BY` then create a text field and update the text field either by workflow rule or Process builder or trigger.

> Formula field is not supported in Group By clause.

There is an idea [Allow SOQL GROUP BY on formula fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HlNtAAK) posted, you could vote for this idea.